# Entity route requirement not working

Tags: nodes, 9

I'm trying to get the following route working but the entity bundle requirement won't work. If I switch requirements to _access: 'TRUE' it works but entity checks are not working. I've traced it to EntityBundleAccessCheck.php where the node parameter is a string containing the node ID instead of the loaded entity, but I'm not sure why.

```
entity.node.send:
  path: '/node/{node}/send'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Send'
    _controller: '\Drupal\nm_resend\Controller\Send::send'
  requirements:
    _entity_bundles: 'node:resend'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
```

Comment: What's your goal? What would a successful outcome look like? What is happening now that differs from that successful outcome?

Comment: The goal is for the route to work for that bundle. The access check fails so I get access denied. I've worked around it for now by using _custom_access instead of _entity_bundles but still not sure why _entity_bundles doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help without the answers to the questions i asked in my last comment.

Comment: I've answered your questions. Goal: The route works and I'm taken to the page served by the controller. What is happening: access check fails causing an access denied